# Value not used for dropdown database search filter

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm using C# Xamarin with an azure database.

I'm trying to only show outputs based on whats in my spinner/dropdown.

I followed the xamarin docs on how to output a toast on whats in the spinner and had all the events displaying. They were not connected at the time.

Then I went to only output events based on whats in the dropdown box(code below) but says values not used and I can't see where the error is.

`eItemsSP` is not used. Whenever I run the app and open the page, it crashes giving a null exception.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit 1: I changed the second line to this

```
private List<EventsDB> eItemsSP = new List<EventsDB>();
```

It no longer crashes and I can use the dropdown box but doesn't display anything.

```
    private List<EventsDB> eItems;
    private List<EventsDB> eItemsSP;
    private ListView eListView;

    protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ISharedPreferences pref = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("UserInfo", FileCreationMode.Private);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Search_Event);
        eListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myListView);

        #region setUpDropdowns
        Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spnSearchEvents);

        spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(spinner_ItemSelected);
        var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(
                this, Resource.Array.professions, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);

        adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
        spinner.Adapter = adapter;
        #endregion


    }
    private async void spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
        string spnCat = string.Format("{0}", spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position));
        eItems = await Client.GetTable<EventsDB>().ToListAsync();
        EventsDB eItemsSP = eItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Category == spnCat);

        ListViewAdapter adapterLV = new ListViewAdapter(this, this.eItemsSP);

        eListView.Adapter = adapterLV;

        //Toast.MakeText(this, spnCat, ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
```

Comment: In which line you get the exception?

Comment: The exception occurs when I open this page, crashes straight away. I pretty sure it's the 3rd last time of code that's the problem. eItemsSP is not used where initialised it at the top, it says